# Monospaced numbers in invoice2

Tags: typewriter, invoice2

I am trying to make an invoice where the entries are all using `ttfamily`, in the `invoice2` package, but can't seem to get the numbers (as opposed to the table text) in monospace.  This is frustrating as it is *especially* the numbers I want monospaced.  How can I get the table to be entirely (or even just for the numbers!) in `ttfamily`?

A minimum example, where the problem is apparent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{invoice2}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily
 \invoiceoptions{vat=.09}
 \begin{invoice}[currency-symbol={\euro{}}]
 \ttfamily
    \invoicesingleitem{Ignition!}{4087.99}
    \invoiceitem{1.5}{The Art of Computer Programming 1--4}{162.99}
    \invoiceitem{20}{The TeXbook}{55.69}
 \end{invoice}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `invoice2` package internally uses the `siunitx` package to format numbers. If you want to change the font of the numbers you can use `siunitx` settings, with the command `\sisetup`.

The settings are described in the `siunitx` [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) on page 18. The default mode for numbers is `math`, which means you can influence the number font by setting the `math-rm` option, in this case to `\mathtt`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{invoice2}
\sisetup{math-rm = \mathtt}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\begin{document}
 \invoiceoptions{vat=.09}
 \begin{invoice}[currency-symbol={\euro{}}]
    \invoicesingleitem{Ignition!}{4087.99}
    \invoiceitem{1.5}{The Art of Computer Programming 1--4}{162.99}
    \invoiceitem{20}{The TeXbook}{55.69}
 \end{invoice}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

If you prefer the Times monospace font then you can also use `\sisetup{math-rm = \texttt}`:

[image]